# I have a problem while deploying my cube from Visual Studio 2019 to SSAS in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, powerbi, ssms, ssas

I created my cube in Visual Studio using an SSAS project and when I try to deploy I get an error and it disappears immediately and I can't read the details:

[image]

But when I go to my SQL Server Management Studio I found the cube:

[image]

I don't know what to do to solve this issue and when I try to use this database in PowerBI I can't connect to it but i can use other databases that I got from othem people:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you building an Multi-Dimensional Model, instead of the newer SSAS Tabular Model? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/tabular-models-ssas?view=asallproducts-allversions

Comment: @David why should I use a Tabular Model?

Comment: Better, faster, easier, newer, more Microsoft investment, more adoption, bigger community.

Comment: I ll try it but I think that it has nothing to do whith the problem of deployement I got

Comment: It definitely has nothing to do with the problem.  It’s just rare for people to be learning Multidimentional these days.

Comment: @David  okay Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're running SSMS as Administrator, but not Power BI.  Elevate for Power BI or add your user account as an SSAS administrator in SSMS.